# How to return actual html file using JAX-RS

Tags: java, html, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

so far, I'm returning html my home page by:

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_HTML})
public String viewHome()
{
   return "<html>...</html>";
}
```

what I want to do is return home.html itself and not copying its contents and returning the string instead.

How do I do this? thanks :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can just return an instance of `java.io.InputStream` or `java.io.Reader` — JAX-RS will do the right thing.

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_HTML})
public InputStream viewHome()
{
   File f = getFileFromSomewhere();
   return new FileInputStream(f);
}
```

Comment: hmm, good suggestion sir.
I'm getting filenotfoundexception -_- Does it search the "tosearch.txt" relative to the calling file?

Comment: That depends what the "current directory" of your application is — which depends on where the app is executed from, i.e. it can (and probably will) change at runtime. `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));` will print the path that relative files are resolved from.

Comment: If you're in a Servlet application, the getResourceAsStream() method (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) is a better option then using a `java.io.File` instance.

Comment: What would be the best way to "load" a file in webapp-dir?

Comment: @Alex if it's a file in the web application itself (that is, under src/main/wwwroot as opposed to in the servlet app's classpath), then calling getResourceAsStream on the ServletContext is the way forward: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 4):

1. Read the File using `getResourceAsStream`
2. write back to returned String.

Answer (score 1):

This is my preferred way of serving a web page using JAX-RS. The resources for the web page (html, css, images, js, etc.) are placed in `main/java/resources`, which should deploy them in `WEB-INF/classes` (may require some configuration depending on how you set up your project). Inject `ServletContext` into your service and use it to find the file and return it as an `InputStream`. I've included a full example below for reference.

```
@Path("/home")
public class HomeService {
    @Context
    ServletContext servletContext;

    @Path("/{path: .+}")
    @GET
    public InputStream getFile(@PathParam("path") String path) {
        try {
            String base = servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/classes/files");
            File f = new File(String.format("%s/%s", base, path));
            return new FileInputStream(f);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // log the error?
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HtmlEasy](https://code.google.com/p/htmleasy/wiki/Installation)  which is built on top of RestEasy, which is a really good implementation of Jax-RS.