# Restful web pages/ sites

Tags: java, rest, servlets, web, jax-rs

I understand the basics of a restful service and how it allows scalability to heterogeneous applications.

But what about creating a restful webpage? For example:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questionss/99999

That url looks pretty restful to me, but how is a traditional response in JSON or XML going to create a webpage like the one you're viewing now?

How do these endpoints handle the html? Can anyone describe this process in regards to JAX-RS and Servlets?

Answer (score 1):

A web page is not RESTful, but the service that *produces* it may be.  I don't know about JAX-RS in particular, but the general idea is not really any different from any other dynamic web service -- the service interprets the request URI and renders an appropriate response.  What makes it RESTful is really just the approach to constructing and interpreting URIs.

Perhaps the trickiest thing about understanding REST in general is accepting that the basic idea is *extremely* simple and generic.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing RESTful with HTML.

[REST (Representational State Transfer)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) describes an architectural style which is based on the HTTP protocol and its operations (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, ...) as well as response status codes and it primarily focues on web resources.

It uses URIs to target local or remote resources where a server in the back which is running a service (f.e. a JAX-RS service) is listening on certain path-segments and will process anything past a certain base-url. F.e a service may be running at http://company.com and have assigned the path `/rest/products` to it. The service will now listen to any invocations of `http://company.com/rest/products/...` and extract certain parameters from the rest of the URL to process a certain request based on the HTTP method you've invoked the server with. A GET request on `http://company.com/rest/products/gtin/12345678` may f.e. request information on the product with the global trade item number 12345678.

It is up to the servic which content it will return. With JAX-RS f.e. a class providing the request above could look like this:

```
@Path("/rest/products")
public class ProductResource {
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Path("/gtin/{gtin}")
    public Response getProductByGTIN(@PathParam("gtin") int gtin) {
        ...
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/xml")
    @Produces("text/html")
    @Path("/")
    public Response addNewProductViaXML(ProductJAXBClass product) {
        ...
    }
}
```

In the example above an invocation of the URL above would try to return a response in JSON format if a JSON provider is available (org.json or jackson f.e). If you invoke `http://company.com/rest/products` via HTTP POST operation and send an XML document of a format which is understood by the server, within the body of the request, you are able to add a new product dynamically to the service.

HTML might just be one of many document formats returned by a web server/service. What you actually receive from the server depends mostly on the server side. You can set certain client headers where you tell the server what kind of documents you wish to receive - but the server is not forced to accept these headers.

While HTML in the sense you might mean it is primarily targeted at humans, RESTful services target no-one but just serve incoming requests - if they are for humans or other computers, they don't care as long as they are capable of understanding the request and have a content handler available to transform an object to a response.

Comment: Is it appropriate to respond with forward to a jsp file similar to servlets? I just dont understand how to format the resource into a webpage.

Comment: In general you are allowed to use redirects as HTTP response codes (as any other status code). However, this would create a different semantics. Instead of the server responding with "I understood your request here is the answer" you would then get something like "I understood your request but better look at x for the answer". In JAX-RS you could [either just load a static page and return its bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489929/how-to-return-actual-html-file-using-jax-rs), create your own HTML answer dynamically or us a [third party library](https://code.google.com/p/htmleasy/)

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays REST is often reduced to services which transfer data as JSON (or sometimes XML) over HTTP.  This does not mean that your webpage is not restful.

Let's take a look at only two points of the [Uniform Interface constraint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Uniform_interface) of a RESTful architecture:

**Identification of resources:** Resources are (normally) identified by a URI and they are independent from their representation. So `/customers/4711` is *one and the same* resource independent if you are using JSON or XML as representation form. A client can send an `Accept` header containing one ore more MediaTypes and via content negotiation the server can find the format that fits best. 
So it is very restful to provide your data also as HTML because this is the MediaType which browsers are using as default. Saying that is not restful to use the standard format of the web does not make any sense. (Hint: when Roy Fielding wrote [his Ph.D](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm) about REST JSON was not invented).

**Hypermedia as the engine of application state:** The idea is that a client knows only the entry point of your application. The response contains all information how the client can proceed. Depending on which choice the client did the server can provide all information for the next step and so on. This is something webpages are doing very well since the beginning by simply using hyperlinks. Many of the "RESTful services" today still lack this important feature. 
One more example how webpages follow this principle is the html form: (taken from "[REST: I don't Think it Means What You Think it Does](http://gotocon.com/dl/goto-amsterdam-2014/slides/StefanTilkov_RESTIDontThinkItMeansWhatYouThinkItDoes.pdf)" - Stefan Tilkov / GOTO Amsterdam 2014):

```
<form action='http://example.com/search' method='GET'>
    Search for: <input type='text' name='query'>
    <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

The server provides an easy to understand recipe how the client can construct the next URI.

To don't ignore your question about JAX-RS: Your resource classes can produce `text/html` but it's your job to generate this HTML with a templating engine of your choice. Or you can simply use JPSs. See also: [The return of JSPs in HTML5?](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/the_return_of_jsps_in)