# Return HTML file from JAX-RS service

Tags: jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I'm building a web app using the following tools:

1. Jersey 2.14 as a the RESTful web service
2. Maven for dependency managing
3. Spring 4.1.3 for Redis and MySQL integration (JDBCTemplate and Spring-data-redis).
4. Tomcat 8 for server.

The integration with the various databases is working well and I managed to create a JAX-RS service that returns simple text or json objects.

For some reason I can't return an HTML file from my JAX-RS service.
This is the `web.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>insider</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.insider</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This is my JAX-RS service (which I mistakenly called a "servlet" in the class name):

```
@Path("/")
public class RoutesServlet {
    @GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    public String index() {
       ...
    }
}
```

Where should I put the static html files?
Am I missing something with the configuration?

Comment: Are you using an MVC framework? If so you generally keep html in `views` folder and the framework will map controllers to views. I'd suggest using [Spring MVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

Comment: @EddieB Isn't Jersey supposed to this as well? I'm not using any MVC framework.

Comment: You can serve your static HTML files from your WAR file directly.  Just place them in the root.  as long as the file is found it will be served from there.

Comment: Your question was already answered here - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489929/how-to-return-actual-html-file-using-jax-rs][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489929/how-to-return-actual-html-file-using-jax-rs